# what distro/theme is that (from a picture)

Tags: linux, theme

Hi I would be grateful if someone could tell me what from this image what distro that is:  [image: https://i.imgur.com/PM4Un3O.png]

Answer (score 1):

it could be any distro... this is just a terminal app i.e roxterminal installed at whatever distro wirh colours adjusted...

Comment: not sure if it is roxterminal, but the multiple red squares is a standard root icon available in most distros called gksu-root-terminal. I have this icon by default in lxde and xfce.

Comment: meaning that you can apply this icon to the existing terminal application, if not already assigned . This red icon goes by default on ROOT terminal.

Comment: more terminals here: http://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators/